# Convert an Url-query into a node

Tags: neo4j, cypher, neo4j-apoc

Im trying to convert an Url-String into a node with cypher:

```
`https://e.whoopidoo.nl/x/plugin/?pName=edit_data&MIDRID=S7Y1Mv2fa2tobGz5P8fW0NzU4n8RUMjYwNIAAAA21&Z=-394462905&utm_source=DMdelivery&utm_medium=email&utm_content=ae9982saa&utm_campaign=aletter%202018"`
```

And convert it to an array with

```
`split(apoc.data.url(u.url).query,"&") as urlArr`
```

Result-array : `["pName=edit_data", "MIDRID=S7Y1Mv2fa2tobGz5P8fW0NzU4n_RrZGhsZmRJQAA67", "Z=-1006289928", "utm_source=DMdelivery", "utm_medium=email", "utm_content=ae9982saa", "utm_campaign=aletter 2018"]`

Could you please help what steps to take:

- How to loop through the `urlArr` with `UNWIND` or `FOREACH` or a `apoc.function` ?
- Then with each value within the loop `split( arrValue, "=") as keyValue`
- How to collect these key-values convert into `(:urlQuery{  collectedKeyVals  })` of this Url

Cypher :

```
MATCH (u:Url)
WITH u, split(apoc.data.url(u.url).query,"&") as urlArr 
// UNWIND or FOREACH - urlArr?
// ... in loop ... split( arrValue, "=") as keyValue
// How to COLLECT efficiently ?
// MERGE or CREATE
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Use the [`List comprehension`](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/syntax/lists/#cypher-list-comprehension) to get a list of key-value pairs
2. Then use the `apoc.map.fromPairs` function to get map from list with key-value pairs
3. And use [`SET`](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/clauses/set/#set-replace-properties-using-map) to set properties from map

---

```
WITH "https://e.whoopidoo.nl/x/plugin/?pName=edit_data&MIDRID=S7Y1Mv2fa2tobGz5P8fW0NzU4n8RUMjYwNIAAAA21&Z=-394462905&utm_source=DMdelivery&utm_medium=email&utm_content=ae9982saa&utm_campaign=aletter%202018" as url
WITH split(apoc.data.url(url).query,"&") as urlArr

// 1
WITH [n in urlArr | split(n, '=')] as keyValuePairs
// 2
WITH apoc.map.fromPairs(keyValuePairs) as keyValueMaps
// 3 
CREATE (U:urlQuery) SET U = keyValueMaps

RETURN U
```

Comment: Thanks, worked! Learned something new :))   [n in urlArr | split(n, '=')] as keyValuePairs

Answer (score 0):

You can use `UNWIND` after creating a node to set these propeties dynamically with apoc.

```
WITH split(apoc.data.url("https://e.whoopidoo.nl/x/plugin/?pName=edit_data&MIDRID=S7Y1Mv2fa2tobGz5P8fW0NzU4n8RUMjYwNIAAAA21&Z=-394462905&utm_source=DMdelivery&utm_medium=email&utm_content=ae9982saa&utm_campaign=aletter%202018").query,"&") as urlArr 
CREATE (N:urlQuery) 
WITH N,urlArr
UNWIND urlArr as urlValue 
CALL apoc.create.setProperty(N, split( urlValue, "=")[0], split( urlValue, "=")[1]) YIELD node
RETURN node
```

Comment: Thanks, Will keep the  apoc.create.setProperty   in mind. 
Although Im wondering, comparing (benchmarking) the UNWIND vs  [ n in urlArr |  ... ] which one is more efficient?